# Store enums in sql-server using Linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, enums

How do you store enums in sql-server using linq-to-sql?

I end up having a lot of conversions to and from `int` in my code.
There has to be a better way. What did I miss?

```
sqlItem.enumValue = (int)myEnumValue;
...
myEnumValue = (MyEnumType)sqlItem.enumValue
```

It does not matter if SQL server or LINQ stores the values as strings or ints in the database, I just want to avoid all these typecasts sprinkled all over my code.

Could it be solved by an extension method to my linq-to-sql-classes and if so what would that look like?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a mapping for types from the database from within the DBML editor.

Assuming you're working from within Visual Studio (the order in which these actions are undertaken can get highly irritating, since it auto-deselects your current selection in the editor when opening the properties, and so on):

- open the DBML editor,
- open the "Properties" view/tab
- specify the type in the "Type" field.

In my experience, just inputting the type in the form of `<namespace>.<type>` is not always successful, I think this is the nuance that @leppie is referring to; for safety, use `global::<namespace>.<type>`.

Comment: Also make sure the `enum` is defined in the same namespace as the `DataContext`, else it fails :\

Comment: Hmm, or was it was to include the `using` statement within the namespace? Too long to remember :)

Comment: @leppie Indeed I did, fixed; I think my updated appropriately addresses the issue you bring up - could you perhaps confirm this for your case?

Comment: It is in a codebase somewhere :) Will try look for it. We are not owners of that code anymore.

Comment: @leppie Typical! :p I play the out-of-scope-for-this-question card.

Comment: If I do this, will I lose these changes when I resynchronize the model with the sql database by deleting all the tables from the designer and then re-adding them to the designer?

Comment: @dontomaso Unfortunately, yes you will.

Comment: Is there a way to make those generated enum fields  nullable for those fields mapped to the ones that say 'CanBeNull=True'?